# How can I clone a .NET solution?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Starting new .NET projects always involves a bit of work. You have to create the solution, add projects for different tiers (Domain, DAL, Web, Test), set up references, solution structure, copy javascript files, css templates and master pages etc etc.

What I'd like is **an easy way of cloning any given solution**.

If you use copy/paste, the problem is that you need to then go through renaming namespaces, assembly names, solution names, GUIDs etc.

Is there a way of automating this?

Something like this would be great:

```
solutionclone.exe --solution=c:\code\abc\template.sln --to=c:\code\xyz --newname=MySolution
```

I'm aware that Visual Studio has project templates, but I've not seen solution templates.

Answer (score 7):

I have created a small application for this. It works just like the previously mentioned Solutionclone app, except that it is both a command line application as well as a WPF application.

Cloney copies a source folder to a target one, without any Git or Svn integration. It will also replace the old namespace everywhere (in file names as well as within files) with the new namespace (the name of the target folder) and exclude certain files (e.g. *.suo, *.user, *.vssscc) and folders (e.g. .git, .svn).

You can grab the source code or download an executable at https://github.com/danielsaidi/cloney.

Cloney can also be added to the Windows Explorer context menu, which makes it possible to clone .NET solutions by just right-clicking the .sln file.

Comment: Happy to hear that! :)

Answer (score 2):

As you already found out: Copy the .sln File and make sure the paths/guids match.

Because the .sln are `text/plain` just use your favourite scripting language to script a cloner.

Maybe this is a good time to learn Python/Ruby/Perl/[Windows Script Host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host)

[MSDN Solution (.sln) File Definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951.aspx)

Comment: On windows? Powershell - seriously capable even before you start pulling .NET assemblies in to play with

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Tree Surgeon](http://www.codeplex.com/treesurgeon/) on CodePlex, it creates a development tree for you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the [Guidance Automation Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=B91066B3-D1D6-4990-A45F-34CF8DBDC60C&displaylang=en) allows you to do this, but may not be an "easy" way.

I have the same problem as you and intend to look at it in detail "real soon now".

Answer (score 0):

May be you should check **Warmup** open source project. Find brief description on http://devlicious.com/blogs/rob_reynolds/archive/2010/02/01/warmup-getting-started.aspx.

IMHO, advantage of **Warmup** approach is that it can clone the whole tree with solution directly from SVN or GIT.

Note! I haven't use it personally, but plan to give it a try in the next project.
Please leave a comment if you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Old post, I know, but I recently had a need to do this, and although there are several homegrown tools out there to do it, I wanted something more lightweight that I could toss around wherever I feel like it. Since I like python for interpreted language scripting, I wrote a single file tool in python to do the job. It's only dependency is python3 and chardet2.

https://gist.github.com/4159114

Answer (score 0):

You can use a multi project template to get solution like behavior. The folder structure will be slightly off putting all the projects into a level below the .sln file.

You can also implement a custom IWizard to have complete control.